# Xcode 8.1 missing Object Library

Tags: xcode

I have an android background, but am just learning how to build iPhone apps using swift. I am using the book Beginning iPhone Development with Swift 2: Exploring the iOS SDK.

Problem is that it refers to Buttons and such being in the Object Library and I don't have anything in my object library. I have clicked on the View as instructed.

I have a newly installed MacBook and am running Xcode 8.1, which is newer than the book's directions. It refers to iOS UIkit, but I don't know how to install this.

I did Single View Application under iPhone to get where I am. Can anyone point me to what I need to do? I am brand new to the Apple world entirely.

Comment: Import UIKit at the top of your swift file

Comment: @toddg not far enough to have a swift file. Looking at the view on the interface builder. Object Library is on the main screen, separate from the interface builder. It says I should be able to drag and drop items, but there's nothing to drag and drop.

Comment: @Rob I have clicked on the view. Updated the question.

Comment: @Rob Figured it out and posted answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aha! In the main window, I clicked on the storyboard and that allowed the Object Library to contain the view items, including buttons.

So, click on the storyboard in the main window, then click on the view in the IB.